# Laravel 5 - Pre-populate a HTML select using database value and old

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to use 'old' in a Laravel 5 app to pre-populate a select form on an edit route like this...

```
<select id="category" name="category" required>
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="animal" @if (old('category') == "animal") {{ 'selected' }} @endif>Animal</option>
    <option value="vegetable" @if (old('category') == "vegetable") {{ 'selected' }} @endif>Vegetable</option>
    <option value="mineral" @if (old('category') == "mineral") {{ 'selected' }} @endif>Mineral</option>
</select>
```

This works well and keeps the selected option if a validation fails, but I am trying to make it work so that it pre-populates when the page first loads.

How do I determine if this is the first load of the edit page, or if it has reloaded after a validation failure? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets imagine you have sent the `category` value as `$category`.
So in every `<option>` tag,

```
<option value="animal" 
    {{ old('category') == 'animal' ? ' selected' :
        $category == 'anumal' ? ' selected' : '' }}>
            Animal
</option>
```

This is what is going on there:

```
if there is an old value and its matching, select this,
else if the original value is matching select this,
else do nothing.
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the second parameter of the *old* function with a default/initial value:

```
<option value="animal" @if (old('category', 'animal') == "animal") {{ 'selected' }} @endif>Animal</option>
```

The second parameter will be returned as the function result if an old value cannot be found in the flashed input.